# Possible Mold under carpet

Tags: wood, mold, carpet

Recently, I noticed that there was something that looked like black mold under a carpet. I am 98% sure that it is not mold but the carpet padding is slowly falling apart. The carpet padding sits on a wooden floor.

I decided that I should send a sample to a lab to be tested. I was recently advised by a friend that it was unnecessary. That is, I am looking for trouble. He points out that mold requires moisture to grow and the area under the carpet is dry and therefore it is not mold.

Is he right?

Comment: The only way to tell mold from something else(stain) is have have it tested.  Most mold is just icky, but a small number are dangerous.  Good chance it is just a stain caused by the padding, but peace of mind is useful to have.

Comment: This is an opinion-based question and not suitable for this Stack Exchange. It is possible for mold to form under carpet on an uninsulated floor, given certain circumstances. We can certainly take on that question if you ask it.

Comment: If this worries you, you could treat it as if it is mold and neutralize it by spraying with vinegar or another mold killing solution. Then you could sleep well at night.

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg To spray it with vinegar means taking  everything out of the room.  That is not a small job. If it is mold, it is something that might need to be done. However, it is not something I want to do on a whim.

Comment: It's dry under the carpet now; can you prove it's never been wet?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the lab results will tell you if your friend is right or not. Besides, what does it matter if he is or not? You get the peace of mind of knowing that it's not mold, or if it is, that's not a harmful mold. If that was worth the price of testing, then your friend's opinion is irrelevant.

Comment: @spuck I am fairly sure that it has never been wet. However, I cannot be 100% sure.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Home remedy to detect and kill possible Mold.

If it is Mold, bleach will kill it just spray and wait.

If it is padding it will stay as is.

Comment: What is "detraining padding"? An internet search indicates that,  "Detraining is the partial or total loss of training-induced adaptations in response to a training stimulus." what's that got to carpet padding or mold?

Comment: @FreeMan thank you for finding my spelling errors and for the DV

Comment: Bleach is not recommended for killing and cleaning up mold. It does not work on porous surfaces (carpets, wood floors, for example) very well at all.

Comment: It was in your comment on the OP, as well, so I thought it was intentional.

Comment: @FreeMan I did not pay attention, and do not know why the auto spell correction will do that.

Comment: The test results came back and they were positive for mold. I am very surprised and unhappy about it.